# JPA and Hibernate dosnt update one to many relation in first try in spring rest with JSON

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have trying spring rest with hibernate, JPA and JSON.
I have to entities like below:

University.java

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "university")
public class University extends BaseEntity {
    private String uniName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "university_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "university_id"))
    private Collection<Student> students;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseEntity {
    private String stuName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("students")
    private University university;

    //setters and getters
}
```

I have this dumy values in my db.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uniName": "uni1",
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "stutName": "st1",
        "university": {
          "id": 1,
          "uniName": "uni1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "stutName": "st2",
        "university": {
          "id": 1,
          "uniName": "uni1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**first try:** When I try to update the university with its student, there is no success 
and this is my hibernate log

```
Hibernate:
    select
        university0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        university0_.uniName as uniName2_5_1_,
        students1_.university_id as universi3_4_3_,
        students1_.id as id1_4_3_,
        students1_.id as id1_4_0_,
        students1_.stuName as stuName2_4_0_,
        students1_.university_id as universi3_4_0_
    from
        university university0_
    left outer join
        student students1_
            on university0_.id=students1_.university_id
    where
        university0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        student
    set
        stuName=?,
        university_id=?
    where
        id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        university
    set
        uniName=?
    where
        id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        student
    set
        stuName=?,
        university_id=?
    where
        id=?
```

**second try:** But when I Post same data for second time it is successful and the hibernate log is

```
Hibernate:
    select
        university0_.id as id1_5_1_,
        university0_.uniName as uniName2_5_1_,
        students1_.university_id as universi3_4_3_,
        students1_.id as id1_4_3_,
        students1_.id as id1_4_0_,
        students1_.stuName as stuName2_4_0_,
        students1_.university_id as universi3_4_0_
    from
        university university0_
    left outer join
        student students1_
            on university0_.id=students1_.university_id
    where
        university0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        student0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        student0_.stuName as stuName2_4_0_,
        student0_.university_id as universi3_4_0_
    from
        student student0_
    where
        student0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        student0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        student0_.stuName as stuName2_4_0_,
        student0_.university_id as universi3_4_0_
    from
        student student0_
    where
        student0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        student
    set
        university_id=?
    where
        id=?
Hibernate:
    update
        student
    set
        university_id=?
    where
        id=?
```

Which is different from first one !!

What I am doing wrong in my hibernate annotations, or if I have missing something in my JSON annotation why the second try working.

UPDATE: this is my **edit service**.

```
@Override
@Transactional/*(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)*/
public T edit(T entity) throws Exception {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

any help and advice is appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that is persisting the data.

Comment: @ Abdullah Khan I update my question

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. Read the Hibernate manual to know how to correctly map a bidirectional OneToMany association.

Comment: I have JSON serializing issue with hibernate manual , I couldn't find solution to give me the proper solution about JSON serializing, I have asked in this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684015/json-serializing-and-deserializing-with-hibernate-jpa-to-have-parent-object-into

Comment: JSON serialising is absolutely nothing to do with Hibernate persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after changing my entities like below it worked perfectly.

University.java

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "university")
public class University extends BaseEntity {
    private String uniName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "university_id")
    private Collection<Student> students;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Student.java

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student extends BaseEntity {
        private String stuName;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "university_id",updatable = false,insertable = false)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "students", allowSetters = true)
        private University university;

        //setters and getters
    }
```

I hope this help someone else that have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your entities like so

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "university")
public class University extends BaseEntity {

    private String uniName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "university", ...) // Check the mappedBy property
    private Collection<Student> students;

    //setters and getters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseEntity {

    private String stuName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("students")
    private University university; // university is bidirectionally mapped to Student 

    //setters and getters
}
```

Comment: I need have both side eagerly and with JSON serializing it have circular, and if I add @JsonIdentity info json serializing is something that not fit my requirements

Comment: For this issue use a different DTO class to map your JSON to the method paramater.

Comment: please be more specific how it would be

Comment: Create a class `UserDTO.java` and have only the specific user fields in the `UserDTO.java` class that you want to serialize. Have your JSON mapped to `UserDTO.java` class instead of the original `User` class.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35079306/3094731) and  [this](https://dzone.com/articles/testing-data-transfer-object-and-rest-controllers).

Comment: Did you fix your problem?